# Socket.io in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I am trying to use Socket.io in my Chrome extension, but for some reason I can't get it to work. The following is the code I have in my background.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='socket.io.js'></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/');

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        socket.send('hi');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

And my manifest.json I have the following for loading the background page and some permissions:

```
"permissions": [
"http://*/",
"http://*/*"
],

"background": {
"page": "background.html"
},
```

This does not work however. When the extension is loaded, it should connect to the Socket.io server, but it doesn't. I am unable to figure out what is causing this. This works perfectly when I simply run the background.html file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `<script src='http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js'>`

Answer (score 3):

According to the **Manifest v2**  **["migration guidelines"](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html#security-checklist)** you should *"remove JS code contained within  tags and place it within an external JS file"*.

Inline JS is not executed at all, so place it in external JS files and then either import them in `background.html` or use the `scripts` attribute of the `background` attribute in manifest, e.g.:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "socket.io.js",
        "background.js"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using its CDN - https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js, and in the manifest.json file add

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.socket.io; object-src 'self'"

Worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

socket.io.js isn't a file on the filesystem, it's supposed to be served by the server of your choosing. In your case, `localhost:8080`.